# JSONP request error

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to make a request to this url:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=apple&limit=5&namespace=0&format=json

...using JSONP.

The function I'm using to make this request is

```
 <script>

 function foo(data)
 {
 var obj = JSON.parse(data);
 console.log(obj);

 }

 var script = document.createElement('script');
 script.src = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=apple&limit=5&namespace=0&format=jsonp?callback=foo'

 document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
 // or document.head.appendChild(script) in modern browsers

 </script>
```

When I load this function in google chrome I get

```
 Refused to execute script from 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=apple&limit=5&namespace=0&format=jsonp?callback=foo' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

... in the console. How do I execute this request? Thanks!!!

Comment: You're setting the source of your script to the contents of that url, that returns a json. Not a jsonp or script source whatsoever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the src URL to the following:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=apple&limit=5&namespace=0&format=json&callback=foo

This should cause the API to send the appropriate JSONP response you are looking for.

**EDIT** - Now with working code.

```js
function foo(data)
{
   console.log(data[0]);
}

 var script = document.createElement('script');
 script.src = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=apple&limit=5&namespace=0&format=json&callback=foo'

 document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
 // or document.head.appendChild(script) in modern browsers
```

Comment: I'm now getting: 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token a' but the error is not coming from my code but from the callback data. Any idea on how to structure the callback to avoid this error?

Comment: thank you very much. i changed console.log(data[0]) to console.log(data) and it now returns a json object!